# Variable value is not changing as expected

Tags: ruby

I am new in Ruby and reading Book of Ruby book. According to the book, below should change the value of the variables a,b,c  to 1, 2, 3 accordingly, but the values are not changing.

```
def xyz
   puts('---xyz---')
   x = 1
   y = 2
   z = 3
   yield( x, y, z )    
end



a = lambda{ puts "one" }
b = lambda{ puts "two" }
c = proc{ puts "three" }
myproc = proc{ puts("my proc") }

xyz{ |a,b,c| puts(a+b+c) }
puts( a, b, c )  #this should output 1,2,3 but it is not giving any output
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried this. and i got the output

Comment: use puts( a.call, b.call, c.call) to get output

Comment: @santosh The point of this exercise from the book the OP is using is to demonstrate the change in behavior between Ruby 1.8 and 1.9, per my answer.

Comment: @rinku See my previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of puts( a, b, c) use puts( a.call, b.call, c.call) to get output. However you will get "one", "two", "three" as output

Comment: but how come I get the output 6?

Comment: You get `6` as the result of the call to `xyz`.

Answer (score 0):

Per section 10.12 of the book, `a`, `b` and `c` are overwritten as the integers 1, 2 and 3 in Ruby 1.8 as a result of the yield, but not in Ruby 1.9, where they remain defined as lambdas. In either case, however, you should be seeing some output.

Here is the excerpt from the book (assuming this is fair use):

[image]

Comment: but how come I get the output 6?

Comment: Please post your entire output and make sure that the code you've posted is exactly the code you've run. Also, please share what version of Ruby you are using.

Comment: I just downloaded the code.  It has `def xyz; puts('---xyz---'); x=1; y=2; z=3; yield( x, y, z); end`, (not `x=5, y=2, z=3`) so `xyz{ |a,b,c| puts(a+b+c) } => 6`, of course.  `a`, `b` and `c` are simply local variables to the block, which are assigned values of 1, 2 and 3, respectively by the method `xyz`.  `puts(a, b, c)` prints the values of the variables `a`, `b` and `c`, whose values are procs; (e.g., `a => #<Proc:0x007fc91d2476e0@(irb):433 (lambda)>`).  Why do you expect the output to be '1, 2, 3'?  This code seems rather odd, but it may make more sense in the context of the book.

Comment: I know the original code had 1 instead of 5, but that's not the code the OP posted. Further, the OP was asking about the output of `puts(a,b,c)` not the output of `puts(a+b+c)` which preceded it. In any event, see the updated answer for details as to how `a`, `b` and `c` get redefined to be integers.

Comment: @user1478137 I edited your question to say `x = 1`, per the book, and given you said that `6` was output. The `6` is coming from the `puts(a+b+c)`.

Comment: Peter, I should have commented on OP's question, but I put it here because of his/her comment about 'output 6'.  I could see no  explanation for why the OP was getting `6`.  I only tried it with 2.0.  I now understand the point.  Thanks.